# Does jvm load app class prior to dependent third party jar?

Tags: jvm, classloader

My app (spring boot app) uses the third party jar: `hutool-all` and it causes some problem when uses with other needed third party jar. So I want to update a java class of `hutool-all`, So I put the java class in my app: `cn.hutool.crypto.GlobalBouncyCastleProvider` and make some change to  it, now the problem is fixed, but I‘m not sure the jvm must load app class first, if jvm load jar first, then the problem still could happen and the function cannot work again.

So my question is: does jvm must load app class first then is third party jar?

```
[1.027s][info][class,load] cn.hutool.crypto.GlobalBouncyCastleProvider source: file:/Users/zhugw/workspace/rsa-demo/target/classes/
[1.031s][info][class,load] cn.hutool.crypto.ProviderFactory source: file:/Users/zhugw/.m2/repository/cn/hutool/hutool-all/5.5.1/hutool-all-5.5.1.jar
```

Comment: This doesn’t depend on the JVM, but the class loader implementation.

Comment: @Holger: What about ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2c13da15

Comment: Depends on whether you’re using old class path or modules.

Comment: If exist some method could specify load app class first explicitly?